# How to edit value of a record when Django admin page of the model gets opened

Tags: django

In my Django app, I have a model that has an `IntegerField` for holding the number of queries done today and another field that holds the date of last modification of that field.

```
class logs(models.Model):
   today_queries = models.IntegerField("today's queries", default=0, help_text="Total number of today's queries.")
   update_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

My problem is that every time I open the Django admin page for the `logs` model, the value for `today_queries` gets retrieved and shown (the default behavior obviously) but that number would be incorrect if tomorrow and other days come (it should be 0).

How can I edit the value of `today_queries` as soon as the Django admin page for the `logs` model gets opened (so that I compare `update_date` with `now` and if it is a new day, reset the value of `today_queries`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in the `change_view` method of your ModelAdmin, check the docs here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Something like this should do the trick:

```
def change_view(self, request, obj_id):
    instance = self.get_queryset(request).get(pk=obj_id)
    instance.today_queries += 1
    instance.save()
    return super(YOUR_MODELADMIN, self).change_view(request, obj_id)
```

Note: some adjustments should be made to this code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it running with your code and some modifications based on my need.
The only complain from Django side was that `obj_id` should be renamed to `object_id`

Comment: Glad to help! Yep, object_id is the proposed name in django source, sorry for shortening it!